# NSURLComponents to get percent encoding

Tags: ios, nsurl, foundation, percent-encoding

According to documentation of `NSURLComponents`:

> If you set the unencoded property, you can then obtain the encoded
>   equivalent by reading the encoded property value and vice versa.

I tried to get the percent encoding versions of the query and path of the url but I miss something:

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];

NSURLComponents * components = [[NSURLComponents alloc] initWithURL:url resolvingAgainstBaseURL:YES];
components.query = @"oauth_callback=http://google.com";

NSLog(@"Encoded: %@", [components URL]); 
//-> Encoded: http://google.com?oauth_callback=http://google.com
//Does not encode "/" or ":"
```

Where do I fail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `NSURLComponent`'s behaviour is right.
From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Types_of_URI_characters):

> In the "query" component of a URI (the part after a ? character), for
>   example, "/" is still considered a reserved character but it normally
>   has no reserved purpose, unless a particular URI scheme says
>   otherwise. The character does not need to be percent-encoded when it
>   has no reserved purpose.